# Why I get the error !Missing $ inserted.<insterted text>$\end{frame}? Reviewed all the document

Tags: beamer, errors

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\boldmath
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\title[Posters]{\VERYHuge Haciendo un poster en \LaTeX}
\author[Alex]{\huge Alexander Borbón Alpízar}
\institute[ITCR]{\Large Instituto Tecnológico de Costa Rica}
\date{Enero-Febrero, 2013}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{}
\maketitle
\vfill
\begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
\bc
{\tiny tiny}\par
{\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
{\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
{\normalsize normalsize}\par
{\large large}\par
{\Large Large}\par
{\LARGE LARGE}\par
{\veryHuge veryHuge}\par
{\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
{\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Introducción}
En este artículo...
\end{block}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Sección 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1 y $\int f(x) dx$
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Sección 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
$\int f(x) dx$
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: There can be no rational justification for loading the `latexsym` package in a `beamer` document, the more so since you're also loading the `amssymb` package. The only possible justification for loading `latexsym` is if you were still using the LaTeX2.09 system of organizing a LaTeX document; note that LaTeX2.09 was superseded by LaTeX2e in 1994 -- 24 years ago by now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in the document.  They are indicated with `% <--`.  The following code compiles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
% \mode { \usetheme{Warsaw} } % <--

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
% \boldmath % <--

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}

\title[Posters]{\VERYHuge Haciendo un poster en \LaTeX}
\author[Alex]{\huge Alexander Borbón Alpízar}
\institute[ITCR]{\Large Instituto Tecnológico de Costa Rica}
\date{Enero-Febrero, 2013}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]{}
  \maketitle
  \vfill
  \begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
    % \bc % <--
    {\tiny tiny}\par
    {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
    {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
    {\normalsize normalsize}\par
    {\large large}\par
    {\Large Large}\par
    {\LARGE LARGE}\par
    {\veryHuge veryHuge}\par
    {\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
    {\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
  \end{block}
  \vfill
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Introducción}
        En este artículo...
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Sección 2}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1 y $\int f(x) dx$
        \item item 2
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
      \begin{block}{Sección 3}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \end{itemize}
        $\int f(x) dx$
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for this nice answer! I have two further suggestions: `\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]`  and `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\VERYHuge}
\title[Posters]{Haciendo un poster en \LaTeX}` instead of having the font size within the argument of `\title`